# C++ class member rvalue assignment

Tags: c++, rvalue

I have seen C++ code that assigns a class member using an std::move call on an rvalue as follows:

```
class Widget {
  std::vector<int> m_data{};

public:
  // 1. OK
  // x contents are copied locally, m_data space is extended if necessary
  void set_data(const std::vector<int>& x) {
    m_data = x;
  }

  // 2. x creates an rvalue that is moved into m_data. What if Widget is dynamically allocated?
  void set_data(std::vector<int> x) {
    m_data = std::move(x);
  }

  // 3. x is an rvalue generated before the call. What if Widget is dynamically allocated?
  void set_data(std::vector<int>&& x) noexcept {
    m_data = std::move(x);
  }
};

Widget* pW = new Widget{};
pW->setData(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3});
```

I don't understand 2 and 3. How is it possible to safely move an rvalue to a class member if the scope of Widget is not the same than the rvalue passed to set_value()?

EDIT: Fixed my code after user17732522 pointed out that the original version was passing an lvalue, not an rvalue to pW->setData();

Comment: `m_data = std::move(x)` moves the vector contents from `x` to `m_data`. Once this completes, the caller is free to destruct `x` whenever it likes. The vector contents are already safely stored in `m_data`. `m_data` is not itself a reference. It's just a regular object (a `std::vector<int>`).

Comment: Moving does not affect lifetimes of the moved objects themselves at all. It only affects ownership of resources owned by the moved object. Could you describe what you think could be a problem with the lifetimes in your scenario?

Comment: @user17732522 OP probably thinks that the assignment copies the reference, rather than moving the contents of the thing the reference refers to. Hence the concern over lifetime. As if the declaration were `std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>> m_data;` and the assignment were `m_data = std::ref(x)`.

Comment: @RaymondChen but isn't the point of rvalue move assignments to assign the memory resource to m_data? Isn't the temporary, rvalue memory transferred to m_data in both 2 and 3?

Comment: `x` itself does not move. The **contents of `x`** are moved. For example, in the case of a `std::vector<int>`, after the assignment, `x` is an empty vector. All the integers that used to be inside the `x` vector are now inside the `m_data` vector.

Comment: What do you call x itself? x is a memory location storing 1, 2, 3. In my mind that memory location is transferred to m_data to avoid allocating a Widget.m_data memory space and copying the contents.

Comment: Surprise: `x` is not a memory location storing 1, 2, 3. In a `std::vector<int>`, x is a structure that contains a pointer to another block of memory, and that other block of memory holds 1, 2, 3. "Moving" the vector is just transferring that pointer from `x` to `m_data` and nulling out the pointer in `x` so that `x` is now an empty vector.

Comment: So this only works because in reality the portion of memory that is moved is only the dynamically allocated memory of std::vector<> x? Which implies that a class passed as an rvalue reference *must* have a move constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250173/discussion-between-robert-kubrick-and-raymond-chen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::move` does not affect the lifetime of the moved object itself. Instead it indicates that ownership over resources owned by the object on which `std::move` is called may/should be taken over by the function to which `std::move(/*...*/)` is an argument.

For example for a `std::vector` moving the object means that the destination vector should take over any dynamic memory allocations made by the source vector containing the vector elements, so that the source vector's state after the move will be that of an empty vector and the state of the destination vector will be that of the source before the move without any allocation or copying of elements needing to take place. The vector objects themselves are not otherwise affected.

`std::move` on a type that doesn't own any resources, e.g. a simple `std::pair<int, float>`, has no effect. It will simply result in a copy as without move semantics.

Comment: ok, limiting the resource move to x dynamically allocated memory makes sense. However, a couple of things: 1) Does this mean that every class passed-in as an rvalue must have a move constructor? 2) Since we can also pass primitive types rvalues to functions (allocated on the stack), does C++ allow class method primitive type rvalue reference parameters?

Comment: @RobertKubrick A class doesn't need a move constructor (or move assignment operator). An rvalue can also be bound to a `const` lvalue reference, i.e. it can be passed to a copy constructor or copy assignment operator as well (although overload resolution will prefer passing to a function which takes a rvalue reference). So a class that doesn't support move semantics will simply do a copy instead.

Comment: @RobertKubrick Passing a primitive type as rvalue reference is normally equivalent to passing as lvalue reference. A function could still overload on rvalue/lvalue and choose whatever differing behavior, but conventionally there shouldn't be any difference since there are no resources to take.

Comment: @RobertKubrick Also note that in your examples overload 2. and 3. would never be used, because you are passing the vector as lvalue in `pW->setData(v);`, not as rvalue.

Comment: I see, so if a move constructor is not provided effectively the compiler reverts back to pre C++11 non-move behavior.

Comment: @RobertKubrick When following the rule-of-zero (meaning not declaring any move/copy constructors/assignment operators or destructors) which should be the default approach for most classes, then the compiler will implicitly declare and define move operations that recursively move every member when that is possible. So usually it is not required to implement move (or copy) operations yourself except for classes whose (ideally only) job is to manage a resource directly. Other classes simply built up from such classes will then have move semantics automatically.

Comment: Good point about lvalue (instead of rvalue as I stated), however the memory resource question I asked is still valid in the context of class Widget.

Comment: I see about the rule-of-zero, makes sense. However does the compiler also reset the pointers of the *moved* x resources to 0, since x can be an lvalue and could be used after Widget::set_data()?

Comment: @RobertKubrick An lvalue is never moved. Move semantics apply only when a rvalue is passed to a function because the move operations use rvalue references which cannot bind to lvalues. `std::move`'s only purpose is to turn a lvalue expression into a rvalue expression so that the move is used.

Comment: @RobertKubrick If a class contains a raw pointer to some memory location and is responsible for freeing that memory, then the memory location is a resource managed by the class and therefore it should follow the rule-of-five instead. The compiler does not zero any pointer automatically, but the move operations of that managing class should. That's exactly what `std::unique_ptr` does. And if another rule-of-zero class uses a `std::unique_ptr`, then the former's implicit move operations will use the latter's explicitly-defined move operations, which zero pointers as necessary.

Comment: That's right, I fixed my question to focus on rvalues. Sorry for the lvalue/rvalue confusion.

Comment: @RobertKubrick Simply `std::move`ing a raw pointer doesn't do anything. A raw pointer counts as primitive type in the sense of the discussion we had so far and so will simply have its pointer value copied in any case. Which is why `std::unique_ptr` or another suitable resource-managing class should usually be used.

Comment: "If a class contains a raw pointer to some memory location and is responsible for freeing that memory, then the memory location is a resource managed by the class and therefore it should follow the rule-of-five instead". I don't understand, if we have a dynamically allocated vector like in std::vector, or any class with dynamically allocated resources as per the goal of my question, then we need to provide a move constructor or not?

Comment: @RobertKubrick The vector itself should almost never be dynamically allocated (i.e. created with `new`). The vector class _internally_ allocates memory and manages that memory resource. So the vector class itself needs to follow the rule-of-five and define all copy/move operations and a destructor explicitly to zero or delete pointers as necessary. A class _using_ a `std::vector` does not do any dynamic allocation itself and so doesn't directly manage a resource. It can follow the rule-of-zero and have the move operations be generated implicitly to use the move operations of the vector member.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. Any class dynamically allocating memory (not just using threads or file handlers) should provide a move constructor. It's a pre-C++11 rule-of-4 (constructor, copy constructor, assignment operator, destructor) that is now rule-of-5.

Comment: @RobertKubrick Yes, but they should usually delegate the responsibility for the dynamic allocation to a class specifically for that job, which in practice means that the dynamic allocation should be replaced by `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr` or `std::vector` (or a user-defined variation of either of the two). Then the class can again use the rule-of-zero.

Comment: @RobertKubrick Non-copy/move constructors are not relevant to the rule. So it was rule-of-three before C++11.

Comment: Yes, rule of 3. Regular constructors are not included in this convention. Reason being the regular constructor is not an option in case of dynamically allocated members I think. And also there can be multiple constructors taking different parameters, so it can't be nailed to just 1 more case.

Comment: @RobertKubrick The rule is specifically about the copy/move operations and the destructor because whether any of them are declared will affect whether or not the compiler will generate the other ones implicitly. For example if you manually declare a destructor in a class, then the language rules say that no move constructor or assignment operator will implicitly be declared. This is a safety measure because if your class needs a manually-defined destructor, then the implicit move operations would very likely not behave as intended for the class semantics. That's why it should be 3/5 or none.

Comment: "An lvalue is never moved." To be fair a non-const lvalue can be moved if passed as std::move(mylvalue)?

Comment: @RobertKubrick `std::move(mylvalue)` is a rvalue expression, which is the whole point of `std::move`. If you want to be pedantic then it doesn't really make sense to say that an expression is moved anyway. Really it should be: "such and such object is moved-from" or "such and such object is moved into" where the object would be the object referred to by the lvalue or rvalue expression. And to actually perform this move operation a lvalue expression referring to the object would need to be passed through `std::move` to get a rvalue expression referring to the object.

Comment: ok, std::move(mylvalue) is an rvalue expression, but effectively the resource being stolen belongs to the lvalue that can be referenced throughout its scope. In the context of my question this makes sense, it's not just to point out a naming detail.

Comment: @RobertKubrick lvalue and rvalue are _value categories_ which are properties of _expressions_, not of _objects_ or _variables_. A resource belongs to an _object_, not an _expression_. When using the name of a variable (irregardless of whether it is an object, a lvalue reference or a rvalue reference), then the naming expression is an lvalue expression. This is purely syntactical.

Comment: It is still true that std::move(mylvalue) leaves a variable reference available that could be manipulated after being moved. This is beyond my original question, but I was pointing out that I am not trying to be pedantic. I am still puzzled about moving resources for something that can still be accessed in the scope of the call.

Comment: @RobertKubrick It is just convention that passing a reference to an object as rvalue to a function (i.e. using `std::move`) means that the function is allowed (or required) to take over its resources. In most cases this means that the object will be in an unspecified state after the call or sometimes it is specified to be some empty state. E.g. a `std::unique_ptr` is guaranteed to be empty after a move construction or assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the object is instantiated in dynamic scope, or not, is completely immaterial as far as move semantics getting used, or not, when passing parameters for an invokation of the object's method, and whether or not the object's methods use move semantics inside the method. It is completely irrelevant.

Whether or not undefined behavior results from usage or non-usage of move semantisc will be determined by factors that are not necessarily relevant to the object's scope.

```
  void set_data(std::vector<int> x) {
    m_data = std::move(x);
  }
```

In this case, the method caller's is responsible for using move semantics for `set_data()`'s parameter. Failure to do so will result in the parameter, presumably, getting copy-constructed. Whatever the case may be, it is immaterial when it comes to move-assignment that takes place when assigning `m_data` from the passed-in parameter. This will happen irregardless of how `set_data()` gets invoked.  The method has no knowledge of how the parameter got passed in.

```
  void set_data(std::vector<int>&& x) noexcept {
    m_data = std::move(x);
  }
```

Here, the caller is responsible for producing a movable rvalue reference. Attempting to pass an lvalue, which would produce a loss of move semantics, results in ill-formed code. This, effectively, forces the caller into employing move semantics when calling this method.

> How is it possible to safely move an rvalue to a class member if the scope of Widget is not the same than the rvalue passed to set_value()?

Again, it is immaterial. Whether `Widget`exists in dynamic scope, or not, is immaterial as far as move semantics related to calling the object's methods. It may or may not indirectly affect whether or not the totality of the object's method calls results in undefined behavior, or not, but the move semantics themselves have no relation to the scope of the object itself.